# Por que trabalhar localmente é mais lento?

Tags: apache, servidor, localhost

Sempre quando subo um servidor local com `PHP` ou `NodeJs`, me deparo com uma lentidão que em uma hospedagem não acontece

O mesmo acontece quando simulo um servidor com `Ngrok`

Ou seja, isso tudo é por conta da capacidade de processamento ou tem outros motivos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no meu ponto de vista, acredito que é por causa do nº de processos e aplicações que a nossa maquina ja estiver a rodar e configurações no firewall também ja que usa protocolos específicos , ja que não esta rodando apenas o apache como fazem os servidores dedicados, acredito ainda que a causa da velocidade nos servidores web, é porque são dedicados e 100% configurados para rodarem serviços específicos, isso deste prioridade de processamento e configurações de redes nos firewalls, ja que o factor conectividade, quando ha firewall no caminho também diminuem muito a velocidade das aplicações, para verificações de segurança e acesso.

Comment: Bem vindo a comunidade